# Can Null-conditional operator (Elvis operator) prevent IndexOutOfRangeException?

Tags: c#-6.0

I am reading null-conditional operator introduced in `C#6.0`.

I did chaining of `?.` operator and came across following function

```
double SumNumbers(List<double[]> setsOfNumbers, int indexOfSetToSum)
{
    return setsOfNumbers?[indexOfSetToSum]?.Sum() ?? double.NaN;
}
```

Can it also handle `IndexOutOfRangeException` or I have to still add ugly `try-catch`?

Comment: No, it cannot. It only handles `null` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, simply because it is a `null-conditional` operator, not an `indexoutofrange-conditional` operator.

One way you could work around it is to use the [ElementAtOrDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.elementatordefault?view=netframework-4.8) method that checks for the index and returns null if its out of range.

Comment: Thanks. So, is it a perfect and safe return statement `return setsOfNumbers?.ElementAtOrDefault(indexOfSetToSum)?.Sum() ?? double.NaN;` 
 @Sreeram

Comment: It should solve your index out of range problem at least.